# Installing Sharepoint 2013 onto machine with already installed Exchange 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, exchange-server

We have a server that already installed Exchange 2013 on it. Can we install SharePoint 2013 onto this machine too. Anyone previously used this configuration? Which problems may arise?

Comment: is this information helps you?

Comment: Of course just waiting if some one did try this configuration.

Comment: I have tried, it broke stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you should not (ever) install SharePoint and Exchange on the same server, it will most likely break the installation.

As both are using different settings and configuration for IIS, you can use virtualization solution like hyper-v if you don't have enough H/W.

Answer (score 1):

MSFT does not recommend this approach, it will cause a lot of issue. If you trying for development purpose then it is ok but for Production, You will not get support from MSFT.

Both software provision web services in IIS so it is really bad in a production environment. 
I think best approach(even for dev), spin up the Separate VMs one for SP and one for Exchange.

[Installing Sharepoint on the same server as Exchange and Remote Web Access (IIS – Sharepoint -RWA – OWA Conflicts)](https://davejsteele.wordpress.com/2012/02/21/installing-sharepoint-on-the-same-server-as-exchange-and-remote-desktop-web-access-iis-sharepoint-rdweb-owa-conflicts/)